# Implementing a navigation controller programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have created 6 view controllers in the following way:

```
Truck_Tracker_AppAppDelegate *delegate = (Truck_Tracker_AppAppDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate;
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[TrucksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TrucksView" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController3 = [[BlockPartyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlockPartyView" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesView" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController5 = [[UserSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserSettingsView" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController6 = [[TOSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TOSettingsView" bundle:nil];
```

I need viewController1, 3, and 4 to be wrapped in a navigation controller programmatically. I found this on Apple Developer's website:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
UIViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

But I need to do it where I've created the viewControllers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's some things you have to understand about UINavigationController first.  By using `UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myViewController];`, you are actually creating the navigation controller for the class myViewController, which automatically grants it a default UIToolBar, and a default UINavigationBar.  And because UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController, it can be freely used in it's place in any function that takes said class as an argument.

I assume you'll be wanting to use this in a UITabbar, so create an individual UINavigationController instance for each view controller, gather them into an NSArray* and set them equal to the  'viewControllers' property on your UITabbar.

Answer (score -1):

You create an NSArray containing pointers to the view controllers and assign the NSArray to the navigation controller's viewControllers property.

Comment: Yeah... It seems someone doesn't understand that this would create a navigation stack, not individual UINavigationControllers ;).   From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers)

Comment: I don't think he wants individual navigation controllers. I think he wants one navigation controller to navigate among viewController1, 3, and 4. That's how I interpreted his statement, "I need viewController1, 3, and 4 to be wrapped in a navigation controller programmatically." Thanks so much for your ever-so-helpful reference to the UINavigationController Class Reference. I would never have thought to look there.

Comment: Ah.  I inferred his intended behavior from the "only view controllers 1,3, and 4" line.